# Reputation change in profile and in rep report are different

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

If I highlight my username a lil dialog shows **215** under todays reputation.

If I visit my profile it shows **175** as today's reputation.

If I visit https://stackoverflow.com/reputation it shows:

```
** rep today: 215
** rep this week (5/22/2011 - 5/28/2011): 554
** rep this month (5/1/2011 - 5/31/2011): 2372
** rep this quarter (4/1/2011 - 6/30/2011): 2989
** rep this year (1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011): 3551
** total rep 4641 :)
```

And my profile shows 2 upvotes without any rep in front of them. I am attaching along a image of the same.
what does it mean? Any explanations? [image]

Here is the snapshot of rep for today:[image]

Comment: What does /reputation give for that missing 40 rep that isn't shown in your screenshot?  Did you delete an answer that was upvoted today, or have a reason to suspect upvotes from today were later removed?  (Deleting could affect whether those "above cap" upvotes shown in your screenshot were really above the cap or not.)

Comment: @Fred Nurk: I don't think I deleted an upvoted answer today, Maybe deleted an answer without any +/- rep if i remember correctly. Added a snapshot for today, does it help in anyway?

Comment: Ugh, an *image* of a text file instead of the text? :(

Comment: Have you recalced any time recently, @Als? A few weeks ago, I had an instance where I was denied 30 points of reputation, similar to this, because I had deleted a +3 answer and recalced. My "rep cap" for the day was set at 170, but I still had to wait 24 hours to recalc again and match my `/reputation`, which properly said 200.

Comment: @Grace Note: I think I did so this month..

Comment: @Fred: I don't have a hosting to upload the entire text somewhere and Can't paste it here...too long.

Comment: If it's been a month, then that wouldn't be the case, then. So much for that theory. Well, at least we knocked that out of the way.

Comment: @Als: What's wrong with including the 20 or so lines from the screenshot directly as text?  Definitely not too long for here.

Comment: I have the same problem. showing 241 reputation on the snippet for today and 239 in the user reputation page

Answer (score 1):

I would first take a look at your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) in more detail. You only showed the last couple lines. I would look at the post IDs it lists and see where the discrepancies are between it and your profile reputation list for today.

If I had to guess, and this is just a shot in the dark, maybe the vote fraud detection script noticed a bunch of upvotes it thought was questionable (i.e. a rapid succession from the same user on a number of your posts). If it removed these, it might not have registered the change everywhere yet, so the other Reputation lists are just lagging.

Answer (score 1):

We won't be fixing the reputation report immediately, but the reputation tab on your profile itself will show deletion actions, etc. that account for the difference now...so there's no reason to even run the report (it may be completely deprecated after this).

You can see more info here: [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)